# How to open mozilla browser from a java application and submit it?

Tags: java

I am wokring on a linux applicaiton which should open an URL in mozilla, populate username and password in the form (url, username and password are obtained from mysql db) and submit it.

Can anyone suggest how to use mozilla API's to do it.

Regards,
Sunil.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to do this via the browser ? Can you not submit a form using an HTTP client application written with (say) [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) ?

If you do need to do this via a browser, must it be Mozilla ? [Watij](http://watij.com/) provides a trivial way to launch a copy of IE, populate fields and submit forms.

Comment: Dear Brain,

I need to do it using a browser.  I looked for Watij it solves my problem, but I its supported only on windows, my applicaiton is on linux.

Do you hava  a similar tool for linux??

Comment: Why do you need to use a browser ? Because of cookies/sessions ? HttpClient can do this for you. I don't know of an equivalent of Watij for Linux, unfortunately.

Comment: The requirement of the application is to login into a customer account and do transcation on his behalf (for eg: paypal).  The login part has to be done by the java application and the user should be able to navigate to further pages.

Can we achieve this using HttpClient?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use JavaXPCOM  please check out the [Mozilla Embedding for Java](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JavaXPCOM)

Here is some sample code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
import java.io.File; 

import javax.swing.*;

import org.mozilla.xpcom.*; 
import org.mozilla.interfaces.*;

/*
Websites ref
http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.tech.java/browse_thread/thread/898ba6751d0c57f7 
http://skrul.com/blog/code/
http://wirestorm.net/blog/?cat=9

*/


public class BrowserTest  implements nsIWebProgressListener,nsIWeakReference, nsIInterfaceRequestor, nsIWebBrowserChrome, nsISHistoryListener{ 
    static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("NativeWindow");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            System.err.println("can't find your library");
        }
    }
    private static final String frameTitle="GRE Embedded";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BrowserConroller controler=new BrowserConroller();
        controler.run();
        new BrowserTest().start();
    } 

    public void start(){


        JFrame f = new JFrame( frameTitle );
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(400, 150);
        Container content = f.getContentPane();
        content.setBackground(Color.white);
        content.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
        content.add(new JLabel("Initializing ... "));
        f.setVisible(true);

        File grePath = null; 
        LocationProvider locProvider; 
        Mozilla mozilla = Mozilla.getInstance(); 

        GREVersionRange[] range = new GREVersionRange[1]; 
        range[0] = new GREVersionRange("1.8.0", true, "1.9", false); 

        try { 
            grePath = Mozilla.getGREPathWithProperties(range, null);
            mozilla.initialize(grePath);
            locProvider = new LocationProvider(grePath); 
            mozilla.initEmbedding(grePath, grePath, locProvider); 
        } 

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
            System.out.println("Error: FileNotFoundException"); 
        } 
        catch (XPCOMException e) { 
            System.out.println("Error: XPCOMException"); 
        } 


        //---------- END GRE INITIALIZATION------------


        nsIServiceManager serviceManager = mozilla.getServiceManager(); 

        nsIAppStartup appStartup = (nsIAppStartup)serviceManager.getServiceByContractID("@mozilla.org/toolkit/app-startup;1", nsIAppStartup.NS_IAPPSTARTUP_IID); 
        nsIWindowCreator windowCreator = (nsIWindowCreator)appStartup.queryInterface(nsIWindowCreator.NS_IWINDOWCREATOR_IID); 

        nsIWindowWatcher windowWatcher =(nsIWindowWatcher)serviceManager.getServiceByContractID("@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1",nsIWindowWatcher.NS_IWINDOWWATCHER_IID); 

        windowWatcher.setWindowCreator(windowCreator); 

        nsIDOMWindow win = windowWatcher.openWindow(null, "http://google.com", "MAIN_WIN","chrome,resizable,centerscreen", null);
        windowWatcher.setActiveWindow( win ); 

        nsIComponentManager componentManager = mozilla.getComponentManager();
        String NS_IWEBBROWSER_CID = "F1EAC761-87E9-11d3-AF80-00A024FFC08C"; //$NON-NLS-1$
        nsIWebBrowser webBrowser = (nsIWebBrowser) componentManager.createInstance(NS_IWEBBROWSER_CID, null, nsIWebBrowser.NS_IWEBBROWSER_IID);
        webBrowser.setContainerWindow(this);
        webBrowser.addWebBrowserListener(this, nsIWebProgressListener.NS_IWEBPROGRESSLISTENER_IID);


//      nsIWebNavigation webNavigation=(nsIWebNavigation)webBrowser.queryInterface(nsIWebNavigation.NS_IWEBNAVIGATION_IID);
//      webNavigation.loadURI("http://www.zdnet.com", nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_NONE, null, null, null);
//      

        nsIBaseWindow baseWindow = (nsIBaseWindow) webBrowser.queryInterface(nsIBaseWindow.NS_IBASEWINDOW_IID);             
        long handle=FindWindow.getHWND( frameTitle );

        baseWindow.initWindow(handle, 0, 0, 0,350,350);
        baseWindow.create();
        baseWindow.setVisibility(true);




//      
//      nsIDOMWindow domWin=webBrowser.getContentDOMWindow();
//      nsIDOMEventTarget domEventTarget= (nsIDOMEventTarget)domWin.queryInterface(nsIDOMEventTarget.NS_IDOMEVENTTARGET_IID);
//      domEventTarget.addEventListener("click", new EventListener(), false);
//      
        //Hide JFrame after it have been initialized
        f.setVisible(true);
//      
//      nsIWebNavigation webNavigation=(nsIWebNavigation)webBrowser.queryInterface(nsIWebNavigation.NS_IWEBNAVIGATION_IID);
//      webNavigation.loadURI("http://www.zdnet.com", nsIWebNavigation.LOAD_FLAGS_NONE, null, null, null);
//      
        appStartup.run(); 
        System.out.println("try termEmbedding"); 
        try { 
            System.out.println("mozilla.termEmbedding(); START"); 
            mozilla.termEmbedding(); 
            System.out.println("mozilla.termEmbedding(); FINISHED"); 
        } 
        catch (XPCOMException e) { 
            System.out.println("Fehler: XPCOMException"); 
        } 
        System.out.println("finished termEmbedding"); 
        System.out.println("All done"); 
    }



    public void onLocationChange(nsIWebProgress webProgress, nsIRequest request, nsIURI location) {
        c("onLocationChange");

    }

    public void onProgressChange(nsIWebProgress webProgress, nsIRequest request, int curSelfProgress, int maxSelfProgress, int curTotalProgress, int maxTotalProgress) {
        c("onProgressChange");

    }

    public void onSecurityChange(nsIWebProgress webProgress, nsIRequest request, long state) {
        c("onSecurityChange");

    }

    public void onStateChange(nsIWebProgress webProgress, nsIRequest request, long stateFlags, long status) {
        c("onStateChange");

    }

    public void onStatusChange(nsIWebProgress webProgress, nsIRequest request, long status, String message) {
        c("onStatusChange");

    }

    public nsISupports queryInterface(String uuid) {
        c("queryInterface");
        return null;
    }



    public nsISupports queryReferent(String uuid) {
        c("queryReferent");
        return null;
    }

    public nsISupports getInterface(String uuid) {
        c("getInterface");
        return null;
    }
    private void c(Object o){
        System.out.println(o);
    }

    public void destroyBrowserWindow() {
        c("destroyBrowserWindow");

    }

    public void exitModalEventLoop(long status) {
        c("exitModalEventLoop");

    }

    public long getChromeFlags() {
        c("getChromeFlags");
        return 0;
    }

    public nsIWebBrowser getWebBrowser() {
        c("getWebBrowser");     
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isWindowModal() {
        c("isWindowModal");     
        return false;
    }

    public void setChromeFlags(long chromeFlags) {
        c("setChromeFlags");    

    }

    public void setStatus(long statusType, String status) {
        c("setStatus"); 

    }

    public void setWebBrowser(nsIWebBrowser webBrowser) {
        c("setWebBrowser");         
    }

    public void showAsModal() {
        c("showAsModal");   

    }

    public void sizeBrowserTo(int acx, int acy) {
        c("sizeBrowserTo"); 

    }

    public boolean onHistoryGoBack(nsIURI backURI) {
        c("onHistoryGoBack");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onHistoryGoForward(nsIURI forwardURI) {
        c("onHistoryGoForward");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onHistoryGotoIndex(int index, nsIURI gotoURI) {
        c(" onHistoryGotoIndex");
        return false;
    }

    public void onHistoryNewEntry(nsIURI newURI) {
        c(" onHistoryNewEntry");
    }

    public boolean onHistoryPurge(int numEntries) {
        c(" onHistoryPurge");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean onHistoryReload(nsIURI reloadURI, long reloadFlags) {
        c(" onHistoryReload");
        return false;
    }


} //public class JavaXPCOM_test1[/code]
```

of course this simply loads a Mozilla Browser in a JFrame but you should be able to get access to form fields from the code to populate and submit them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will try this out, hopefully it solves my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do almost any thing by the help of webdriver

Following is my code for login into website

```
WebDriver driver = new FireFoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://172.16.16.219:9081/LOSWebApp/security/login.htm");
         WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3000);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.name("ssoId"))));

    WebElement userid = driver.findElement(By.name("ssoId"));
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
    WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.name("button")); 
    userid.sendKeys("userID");
    password.sendKeys("pwd");

    loginButton.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a JNI library which allows you to access the methods from Mozilla. Probably the most simple solution is to use [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) and create a browser with `SWT.MOZILLA` (see this [snippet](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#printmozillapath) for an example).

Note that you just get a browser widget, not a fully featured browser like Firefox.

Comment: Dear Sir,

Thanks for the response.

My applicaiton has to open a new instance of mozilla everytime a url is selected from the list box populate login details and submit it.  Not sure if using a widget will serve my purpose.

Regards,
Sunil.

Comment: You can create a new Shell (=new window) for each browser widget. So I don't see your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [MozSwing](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mozswing/)  ?

[image]

more info [here](http://www.kabatology.com/09/10/mozswing-a-smart-browser-built-on-xul-and-java-swing/)

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own greasemonkey script to call submit

Comment: How can we invoke the greasemonkey script from java applicaton??

Answer (score 0):

OK, This may come pretty late... but you can use Selenium WebDriver to achieve what you are looking for.

You can create a new instance of a Mozilla window and manipulate forms with it.